# SQLite GROUP_CONCAT from another table, multiple joins

Tags: sql, sqlite

Having trouble with my sql query. Not an SQL expert by any means.

`SELECT
      transactions.*,
      categories.*,
      GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tagName) as concatTags
    FROM transactions
    INNER JOIN categories
      ON transactions.category = categories.categoryId
    LEFT JOIN TransactionTagRelation AS ttr
      ON transactions.transactionId = ttr.transactionId
    LEFT JOIN tags
      ON tags.tagId = ttr.tagId;`

(There's also a where and group by, but didn't think it was relevant to the question).

I'm trying to get:

```
transactionId1, ...otherStuff..., "tagId1,tagId2,tagId3"  
transactionId2, ...otherStuff..., "tagId1,tagId3"
```

What I have now seems to merge the tags into one transaction or something. I tried adding a GROUP BY transactionID at the end, but it gives a syntax error for some reason. I have a feeling my joins are incorrect, but I wasn't able to get anything better.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT t.*, c.*,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tg.tagName)
        FROM TransactionTagRelation ttr JOIN
             Tags tg
             ON tg.tagId = ttr.tagId
        WHERE t.transactionId = ttr.transactionId
       ) as concatTags
FROM transactions t JOIN
     categories c
     ON t.category = c.categoryId;
```

This eliminates the `GROUP BY` in the outer query and allows you to use `t.*` and `c.*` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: What if I want to use tags for filtering in this query?  
(Also why did my `GROUP BY` cause an error?)